# In how many possible ways can we assign the numbers from 1 to 12 to the edges

Tags: geometry

The twelve edges of a cube are assigned numbers 1 to 12. No two edges have the same number. Each of the vertex is concurrent with three edges. The weight of a vertex is the sum of three numbers concurrent with that vertex. In how many possible ways can we assign the numbers from 1 to 12 to the edges so that each vertex will have the same weight??

Answer (score 2):

0 ways (this is not possible)!

Let $v \in \{1, 2, \dots, 8\}$ denote a vertex of the graph and $e \in \{1, 2, \dots, 12\}$ denote an edge of the graph. Let $w(v)$ denote the weight of vertex $v$.

All vertices must have the same weight $A$; that is, $\forall v \in \{1, \dots, 8\}, w(v) = A$, so, the total sum of weights is $8A$.

Another way to calculate the total sum of weights is to sum the numbers on the edges and multiply by 2 (because of the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)); this gives a total weight of $2 \sum_{e=1}^{12} e = 12 \times 13$.

Finally, we have $12 \times 13 = 8A \Rightarrow A = 19.5 \notin \mathbb{N}$.